# Изменение стиля по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, css, style

Пробую изменить стиль списка по нажатию кнопки. Из строки переводится в колонку, а обратно не хочет. Подозреваю из-за унаследованных свойств по умолчанию. Подскажите тривиальный приём для решения

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("ull");
var li = document.getElementById("li");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
console.log(window.innerWidth);

function btnclk() {
  if (ul.style.flexDirection == "row") {
    return ul.style.flexDirection = "column"
  };
  if (ul.style.flexDirection == "column") {
    return ul.style.flexDirection = "row"
  }
};

btn.onclick = btnclk;
```

```css
html,
body,
{
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  border: solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 6px;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row;*/
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav a {
  margin: 3px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 4px;
  align-items: center;
}

nav li {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Room</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav>
        <ul id="ull">
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li id="li"><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Жать"></input>
</body>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: А можете добавить минимально запускающийся пример? с вашей разметкой и стилями, которые есть у разметки до того, как вы запускаете данную функцию?

Comment: `=` производит присваивание. Используйте `==` для сравнения или `===` для сравнения значения и типа.

Comment: Я добавил код и поменял присваивание на сравнение. Так теперь вообще не реагирует.

Comment: @Алексей Я добавил в свой ответ рабочий вариант вашего кода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элементарно, ватсон, вы присваивание вместо сравнения в условии написали

```
if (ul.style.flexDirection = "...") {
```

поменяйте на

```
if (ul.style.flexDirection == "...") {
```

И еще учтите, что до того, как вы запишите что-то в `ul.style.flexDirection`, его значение будет `''`, хоть оно и выглядит как 'row'. оба ваших условия не выполнятся. Лучше сделать так -

```
ul.style.flexDirection = (ul.style.flexDirection == "column")?"row":"column";
```

**UP:**

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("ull");
var li = document.getElementById("li");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
console.log(window.innerWidth);

btn.onclick = () => ul.style.flexDirection = (ul.style.flexDirection == "column")?"row":"column";
```

```css
html,
body,
{
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  border: solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 6px;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row;*/
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav a {
  margin: 3px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 4px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Room</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav>
        <ul id="ull">
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li id="li"><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Жать"></input>
</body>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Стыдно, конечно, но да. Но, кстати,вообще не работает теперь

Comment: @Алексей обновил ответ, оно не работает из за того что изначально там не row и не column, а пустая строка

Comment: Красиво. Я пошел от обратного if (ul.style.flexDirection !== "row").... Так что тоже решил

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("list");

function toggle() {
  el.style.flexDirection = (el.style.flexDirection == 'row') ? 'column' : 'row';
}
```

```css
ul#list {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" style="flex-direction: row;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<button onClick="toggle();">Change direction</button>
```